# GET http://localhost:8080/app/index.jsx.js 404 (Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

Working on react application, i don't understand where the `index.jsx.js` come from i have only `index.jsx`, conf webpack is set:

```
entry: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/', // Specify the local server port
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', // Enable hot reloading
        './src/app/index.jsx' // This is where Webpack will be looking for the entry index.js file
    ],
resolve: {
        modules: [
            'node_modules',
            'src',
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
        ],
        extensions: ['.jsx', '.js']
    },
```

any ideas ??

Comment: Try replacing './src/app/index.jsx' with './src/app/' or './src/app/index'.

Comment: Solved, thak you.